# Scala String to Java Util Date Conversion

Tags: scala, date, date-conversion

Hi the Conversion of String to Date is not possible here..

I search and use several methods but the error can not change..

here the date format is  **var q**  and convert that to **formatedDate**  that is String

then the String convert into util date..

**SearchDate** is from  method **parameter** and the **value of SearchDate is "Thu Aug 29 00:00:00 IST 2013"**

```
    var q: Date = SearchDate
    var dateStr = q.toString()
    var formatter: DateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("E MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy")
    var dat = formatter.parse(dateStr)
    var cal: Calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
    cal.setTime(dat)
    var formatedDate = cal.get(Calendar.DATE) + "-" + (cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1) + "-" + cal.get(Calendar.YEAR)
    println("formatedDate : " + formatedDate)
    val date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm").parse(dateStr)// Error Occured Here..
```

the error  is

Exception in thread "main" java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Thu Aug 29 00:00:00 IST 2013"
    at java.text.DateFormat.parse(Unknown Source)

please share your answers ..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're trying to parse `"E MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy"` formatted date string as `"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"` formatted one, in this line:

```
val date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm").parse(dateStr)
```

No wonder it fails.

Maybe you took the wrong date format for second `SimpleDateFormat` instance by mistake? Or maybe you're passing wrong parameter to `parse()` ?

**edit**

It looks like you actually wanted to call:

```
val date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm").format(dat)
```

Comment: The one you used in the first SimpleDateFormat

Comment: how to convert E MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy format to yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm this format

Comment: You first call `parse` with the first date format, get a date, and then you call `format` on the second formatter with that date. See the edit.

Comment: the date type is String not Date

Comment: @Mila `Date` doesn't have any format information, I assumed that when you want a date in particular format, then you actually want is date formatted **as a String** using that format.

Comment: ok @soulcheck it's a humble request that string how to convert to utildate..

i really don'nt know how to do that

Comment: @Mila you DID that in the fourth line of your code. The only problem there is that IST acronym is ambigous - there are many timezones called IST.

Comment: if you wanna hear my advice, don't use java.util.date or any other class of that if you use java 8 use java.time.instant and so on